# yq doesn't recognize 'del()' command in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: shell, gitlab, gitlab-ci, yq

My yq is kinda throwing a tantrum in my gitlab-ci.yaml. The version of yq within the shell of my gitlab server is 4.16.2 and my local version where I test it is 4.35.2.

According to [Official yq docs](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/delete)  I am indeed using the correct syntax. I mean it works locally, it just doesnt work on my gitlab server for some reason eventho both have yq version 4.x.x

My gitlab-ci code where this happens looks as follows:

> $ if [ $AUTH_ENABLED = true ];
>
> then yq eval -i '.data.auth =
> "'$SECRET'" ' secret.yaml;
>
> else yq -i 'del(.data)' secret.yaml; fi

And then it throws:
***Error: unknown command "del(.data)" for "yq"***

I'm not sure if I'm missing something here but I just can't figure out what the issue here is.

Comment: Just an idea to verify the syntax: Is the command accepted on gitlab if you do NOT do inplace editing, i.e. when removing the `-i`?

Comment: I had completely missed the changes since 4.18.1 like @pmf has noted. I just wasn't providing "eval" in the command. I just updated yq to latest version and it started working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With mikefarah's yq version [v4.18.1](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/tag/v4.18.1) "eval is now the default command, you can leave it out". With versions prior to it, including 4.16.2, you have to provide the `eval` (or `e`) command. So, change

```bash
else yq -i 'del(.data)' secret.yaml
```

to

```bash
else yq -i eval 'del(.data)' secret.yaml
```

or

```bash
else yq -i e 'del(.data)' secret.yaml
```

Just like you did with the command in the `then` branch.

Comment: That was indeed the issue, completely missed those changes. Thanks a lot!